# JavaScript, failing to detect line break

Tags: javascript, replace

I found a bug in my code:

**This code replaces some regular text with a highlighted version:**

```
var param = getCurrentParam();
var text = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = text .replace(param, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+param+'</span>');
```

**But this wont work in this case:**

```
param = 'my text more text another line here';
```

**"Real" html:**

```
my text more text
another line here
```

Because there is a line break (**no br, just enter key in the text editor**), the param has just white space, but in reality (in the html) the text had something (i guess as such): `'\n'`;
So the replace wont work, because there is probably a: "\n" but it searches instead for a " ";
**How can I fix my replace method?**

Comment: You could replace newlines with spaces before replacing the param text, like `text = text.replace( "\n", " ");`.  Would that work for you?

Comment: what about changing getCurrentParam(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since line breaks are normally not visible in html, you could just strip them completely

```
 var text = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');
```